# Some issue in codeigniter

Tags: angular, codeigniter-3

Not inserting the data into table

I have created a web service,  in code igniter, but it is not inserting the data.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: 
GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Accept- 
Language,Content-Language,Content-Type');
$formdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$email=$formdata['email'];  
$password=$formdata['password'];  
$first_name=$formdata['first_name'];  
$last_name=$formdata['last_name']; 
$phone=isset($formdata['phone'])?$formdata['phone']:''; 
$save_data= []; 
$save_data['email']=$formdata['email'];  // 

$this->db->insert('tbl_users', $save_data);


Invalid query: INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (`email`, `phone`, `is_active`, `is_verified`, `email_verified`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '', 1, 1, 1, '2019-08-22 11:26:11', '2019-08-22 11:26:11')
```

Comment: Why codeigniter creating null value in email?Any idea

Comment: Pranav: Its creating all values to null that is coming from angular request,If i am printing save_data, it is showing all the data

Comment: Are you seeing the formdata if you echo after this line - $formdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);?

Comment: Yes. (Ansuman)  print_r($save_data);  // working here but not working in-   $this->db->insert('tbl_users', $save_data);

Comment: @AshishKumar Could you share the complete codes since that codes doesn't produce the query you've said

Comment: @ Hasta- The code is similar to above,If i am printing $save_data, its printing all the data